# Django TypeError 'QueryDict' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I've looked for posts that have endured the same problem that I'm currently facing. But I haven't found a solution. What my problem is:

I have a list of tags. Generated by `{% for tag in all_tags %}`. Each tag has a tagstatus form. When a user selects an option from a drop down, the form submits and is supposed to save the TagStatus object (Tags are foreignKey'd to TagStatus). However, what returns is this:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 'QueryDict' object is not callable
```

**html:**

```
<form class="nice" id="status-form" method="POST" action="">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="hidden" name="status_check" />
     <input type='hidden' name="tag" value="{{ tag }}" />
     <select name="select" id="positionSelect" class="input-text category" onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <option name="all" value="0">Your Status</option>
          <option name="investing" value="1">Status 1</option>
          <option name="selling" value="2">Status 2</option>
          <option name="interested" value="3">Status 3</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def tags(request):
    all_tags = Tag.objects.all()
    context = base_context(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'status_check' in request.POST:
            status = request.GET('status')
            tag = request.GET('tag')
            user = request.user
            tag_status, created = TagStatus.objects.get_or_create(status=len(status), tag=tag, user=user).save()

            response = simplejson.dumps({"status": "Successfully changed status"})
        else:
            response = simplejson.dumps({"status": "Error"})
            return HttpResponse (response, mimetype='application/json')
    context['all_tags'] = all_tags
    return render_to_response('tags/tag.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**models.py** (if its relevant):

```
class TagStatus(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=tag_statuses)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.status

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TagStatus, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

From what I gather it has something to do with the status not being a number. But when I convert it to a int. I get the same error. Please help me. Why is this happening? And whats the fix? I'm not quite sure how to solve this problem. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I believe the error you're encountering is in these lines:

```
status = request.GET('status')
tag = request.GET('tag')
```

request.GET is a QueryDict, and adding () after it attempts to "call" a non-callable object. It appears the syntax you're looking for is dictionary lookup syntax instead:

```
status = request.GET['status']
tag = request.GET['tag']
```

Comment: More errors are following. But yes that was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: For me it was using the @property on the function, makes it a property so call without ()

Answer (score 7):

or just call GETs get to get your values

```
status = request.GET.get('status')
tag = request.GET.get('tag')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def add(request):
    var1 = int(request.GET.get("num1"))
    var2 = int(request.GET.get("num2"))

    res= var1+var2
    return render(request,'calc/result.html',{'Result':res})
```

Comment: Explain the code for better understanding and how this is a solution to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
status = request.GET.get['status']

tag = request.GET.get['tag']
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.